# How to find whole Solr index query into Solr logs?

Tags: solr

I tried to find the Solr index query along with its payload into logs (.../server/logs) but I could not. Do I need to change log level for this?

Comment: did you mean what user is searched. ? `q` value in logs ?

Comment: @vinod: No, I was not asking about search query, I was asking about index query. So, there will be no q param there.

Comment: will be helpful if you can tell what is index query.